# Foreach in R: optimise RAM & CPU use by sorting tasks (objects)?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, ram, doparallel

I have ~200 .Rds datasets that I perform various operations on (different scripts) in a pipeline (of multiple scripts). In most of these scripts I've begun with a `for` loop and upgraded to a `foreach`. My problem is that the dataset objects are different sizes (x axis is size in mb):

[image: filesizes]

so if I optimise core number usage (I have a 12core 16gbRAM machine at the office and a 16core 32gbRAM machine at home), it'll whip through the first 90 without incident, but then larger files bunch up and max out the total RAM allocation (remember Rds files are compressed so these are larger in RAM than on disk, but the variability in file size at least gives an indication of the problem). This causes workers to crash and typically leaves me with 1 to 3 cores running through the remainder of the big files (using `.errorhandling = "pass"`). I'm thinking it would be great to optimise the core number based on number and RAM size of workers, and total available RAM, and figured others might have been in a similar dilemma and developed strategies to address this. Some approaches I've thought of but not tried:

Approach 1: first loop or list through the files on disk, potentially by opening & closing them, use `object.size()` to get their sizes in RAM, sort largest to smallest, cut halfway, reverse the order of the second half, and intersperse them: smallest, biggest, 2nd smallest, 2nd biggest, etc. 2 workers (or any even numbered multiple) should therefore be working on the 'mean' RAM usage. However: worker 1 will finish its job faster than any other job in the stack and then go onto job 3, the 2nd smallest, likely finish that really quickly also then do job 4, the second largest, while worker 2 is still on the largest, meaning that by job 4, this approach has the machine processing the 2 largest RAM objects concurrently, the opposite of what we want.

Approach 2: sort objects by size-in-RAM for each object, small to large. Starting from object 1, iteratively add subsequent objects' RAM usage until total RAM core number is exceeded. `Foreach` on that batch. Repeat. This would work but requires some convoluted coding (probably a for loop wrapper around the foreach which passes the foreach its task list each time?). Also if there are a lot of tasks which won't exceed the RAM (per my example), the cores limit batching process will mean all 12 or 16 have to complete before the next 12 or 16 are started, introducing inefficiency.

Approach 3: sort small-large per 2. Run `foreach` with all cores. This will churn through the small ones maximally efficiently until the tasks get bigger, at which point workers will start to crash, reducing the number of workers sharing the RAM and thus increasing the chance the remaining workers can continue. Conceptually this will mean cores-1 tasks fail and need to be re-run, but the code is easy and should work fast. I already have code that checks the output directory and removes tasks from the jobs list if they've already been completed, which means I could just re-run this approach, however I should anticipate further losses and therefore reruns required unless I lower the cores number.

Approach 4: as 3 but somehow close the worker (reduce core number) BEFORE the task is assigned, meaning the task doesn't have to trigger a RAM overrun and fail in order to reduce worker count. This would also mean no having to restart RStudio.

Approach 5: ideally there would be some intelligent queueing system in `foreach` that would do this all for me but beggars can't be choosers! Conceptually this would be similar to 4, above: for each worker, don't start the next task until there's sufficient RAM available.

Any thoughts appreciated from folks who've run into similar issues. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've thought a bit about this too.
My problem is a bit different, I don't have any crash but more some slowdowns due to swapping when not enough RAM.

Things that may work:

- randomize the iterations so that it is approximately evenly distributed (without needing to know the timings in advance)
- similar to approach 5, have some barriers (waiting of some workers with a while loop and `Sys.sleep()`) while not enough memory (e.g. determined via package {memuse}).

Things I do in practice:

- always store the results of iterations in foreach loops and test if already computed (RDS file already exists)
- skip some iterations if needed
- rerun the "intensive" iterations using less cores

Comment: Interesting ideas, thanks. So potentially `while (Sys.procmem() > (Sys.filesize * 62))` [62 looks to be a rough compression ratio for .Rds to RAM but I'll do more checking]. Possibly `foreach`'s `when(cond)` is a drop-in replacement for `while` here... but I'm not sure it's possible to assign this to workers, it looks like it's evaluated before handing tasks to workers. I'll play around with the while/sleep idea, that's neat. Cheers!

Comment: 62 as a ratio? :O

Comment: aye possibly! [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/remember-to-use-the-rds-format/) reckons so; I'd be looking to test it myself on my files.